# Is there a way to dynamically set y attribute for an image element inside svg element?

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

As stated in the question, I wonder if there is a way to set y attribute for an image element inside svg, because everytime user provides different image, I need to change image’s “y” attribute value.
Right now when I try to use binding in Angular, I get the following error:

[image]

My code for embedding image inside svg looks like this:

```
            <svg class="conversation-image-preview">
              <image *ngIf="inConversationIconInfo.previewUrl" 
              [attr.href]="inConversationIconInfo.previewUrl" 
              [y]="inConvImageY" 
                 />
            </svg>
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: did you try `[attr.y]="inConvImage"`?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript strict mode-only exception "setting getter-only property" occurs when there is an attempt to set a new value to a property for which only a getter is specified.

In your case SVGImageElement is only having getter element, and when you trying to attempt set value it throwing error in console.

You can see in [document of SVGImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGImageElement) where y attribute is `read only`.